# SpringSecurity enable formLogin without login page

Tags: spring-security

It is possible to enable formLogin in Spring Security but only having the 'POST' endpoint accessible?

I don't need a HTML login page because I only wan't to make a http call with username and password in order to authenticate the user.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin()
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT: The thing is I don't want a Spring Boot generated login page. The login page will exist but it will be developed in a different frontend project, so It will need to call this POST endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your question got down voted was for the reason of Cross Site Request Forging (CSRF)

Without a login page, you'd have to disable CSRF, and this is not desirable.

now, if you want to brute force it, send the login page somewhere else

```
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/does-not-exist")
```

this is ugly, because Spring will attempt to redirect to that page.

you can still achieve it, without enabling form login

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class));

    //here you can setup success handlers etc

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilter(myAuthFilter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want a Spring Boot generated login page. The login page will exist but it will be developed in a different frontend project, so It will need to call this POST endpoint. 
Maybe your second option is valid for my needs, I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: This second option is the correct answer for me. I added the AuthenticationManager exposing the authenticationManagerBean method instead of using sharedObject. Thanks.

Comment: great. both options can work if configured. now, you may want to add the `success handlers` and `failure handlers` to your filter too.